# Looking for a specific Sci-fi Anthology book. It's older, 1970's maybe. The book was a best of Sci-fi. Don't think it was Years best SF

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, clones

The story I'm looking for was about a guy who cloned himself near the end of his life. The original went to retire (and die) on a space station unable to contact anyone outside the station. The clone ended up living ages and watched society evolve. The clone may have also dated the clone of his crush?

It tackled the ethics of copying consciousness and was the first Sci-fi story I read that actually made me love Sci-fi. I would love to find it, but infuriatingly I can't remember much else. I know it was in a best of short stories fiction book, and I can't remember any other stories in the book. I don't think it was Years Best SF.

I will update this post if I find/remember anything else.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you looking for the anthology this story was in, or are you trying to identify the story itself?

Comment: Apart from the date you mentioned (1970s) this sounds a lot like the 2005 novel Mindscan by Robert Sawyer.  In it, the MC has a terminal illness and does copy his consciousness into an avatar bod He goes to the moon to wait to die. Meanwhile back on Earth his avatar does start dating the avatar of a woman the original MC had met during the transfer process.  Other ramifications were discussed.  The novel was expanded from a short story.  But even then I don't think the short story was from 1970s.  You might check:  https://www.fantasticfiction.com/s/robert-j-sawyer/ for his anthologies.

Comment: Can you remember whether the anthology was one from an annual series, or a one-off? And was it illustrated? Some of the one-offs I've seen have one or two illustrations per story, sometimes full-page. Perhaps to make them more acceptable to buyers who don't normally read SF.